# I cannot read negative values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data set as follows it includes some negative values. I have written codes to read those values. But when any negative numbers percent. It gives error. File format is as below

```
   1SOL    HW1    2   1.4788   2.7853  -0.7702
   1SOL    HW2    3   1.4640  -2.8230   0.6243
   2SOL     OW    4  -1.5210   0.9510  -2.2050
   2SOL    HW1    5   1.5960  -0.9780   2.1520
```

I have written code as follow. I am using for loop and if function to select P[3], P[4], P[5] positions.

```
X=[]
  P = line.split()
  x = float(P[3]) `#then I collect these numbers in to array like X = []`
  X.append(x)
```

This code work if there is no negative values.

Then I used following function to write X in to another file. But it is not working

```
A.write('%s\n' % (X)) `# this is not working since it X is Float. File open as A to write`
```

Please some one help me to correct my cords.

Comment: What does it do instead of returning the negative value?

Comment: Could there be a space between the minus sign and the number?

Comment: No there is no space between value and negative sign  it says that '-' string cannot convert to float

Comment: Then there IS a space between the value and the negative sign. It's split the values and come up with one item which is just `"-"`, and trying to convert to float. Check your data again.

Comment: This works fine for me. @Shanaka are you sure that's the file you are working with?

Comment: Instead of just describing the error, please post the actual error string and traceback. It usually has useful information that, even if it doesn't help you, will help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `A.write('%s\n' % (X))` doesn't work has nothing to do with `X` being a `float`.

There *may* be a problem in that `(X)` isn't a `tuple` of one float as you seem to expect, it's just a `float`. Commas make a tuple, not parentheses. In particular, comma-separated values anywhere that they don't have some other meaning (function arguments, list members, etc.) are a `tuple`. The parentheses are only there to disambiguate a `tuple` when the comma-separated values would otherwise have another meaning. This is usually simple and intuitive, but it means that in the case of a one-element tuple, you need to write `(X,)`.

However, even that shouldn't be a problem: `'%s\n' % 3.2` is `'3.2\n'`.

On top of that, `X` isn't actually a `float` in the first place, it's a `list`. You explicitly created it as `X = []`, and then `append`ed each `float` to it. Again, that's not a problem, but it means you're possibly not getting the output you *wanted*. This is just a guess, since you never explained what output you wanted or what you were actually getting. But `'%s\n' % [3.2, 3.4]` is `'[3.2, 3.4]\n'`. If you wanted each one on a separate line, you have to loop over them, explicitly or implicitly—maybe `''.join('%s\n' % x for x in X)`.

---

As for why your negative numbers don't work, there are many possibilities, and it's impossible to guess which without more information, but here are some examples:

- There is something that Python (more specifically, `split()`) considers whitespace, even if it doesn't look like it to you, between the `-` and the numbers. So, you're trying to convert `"-"` to a float rather than `"-12345"`.
- Those apparent `-` characters are actually a Unicode minus rather than a hyphen, or something else that looks similar. `.decode`-ing the file with the right encoding might solve it, but it might not be enough.
- There are invisible, non-spacing characters between the `-` and the first digit. Maybe Unicode again, or maybe just a control character.

In many cases, the exception string (which you didn't show us) will show the `repr` of the string, which may reveal this information. If not, you can `print repr(P[3])` explicitly. If that still doesn't help, try `print binascii.hexlify(P[3])` (you'll have to `import binascii` first, of course).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell what will work because we can't see your source file, but the problem you're having is with your `split` function. If I were you, I'd try `P = line.split('\t')` and see if that resolves your issue.